# DigitalOcean AppPlatform deploy via Dockerfile won't start due to gunicorn worker exit

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, digital-ocean

i have a problem. I'm trying to deploy my Flask api via DigitalOcean's AppPlatform, while I'm trying to run my container via localhost on my machine everything works fine, but when an app is build via Dockerfile on AppPlatform there is a problem with starting

```
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:42] [2021-08-15 13:28:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:42] [2021-08-15 13:28:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:42] [2021-08-15 13:28:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:42] [2021-08-15 13:28:42 +0000] [3] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:42] [2021-08-15 13:28:42 +0000] [4] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47] [2021-08-15 13:28:47 +0000] [4] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47] Traceback (most recent call last):
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]     worker.init_process()
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]     self.run()
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 125, in run
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]     self.run_for_one(timeout)
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 62, in run_for_one
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]     self.notify()
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 75, in notify
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]     self.tmp.notify()
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/workertmp.py", line 46, in notify
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]     os.fchmod(self._tmp.fileno(), self.spinner)
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47] PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47] [2021-08-15 13:28:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4)
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47] [2021-08-15 13:28:47 +0000] [3] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47] Traceback (most recent call last):
[back-cany] [2021-08-15 13:28:47]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
```

Do you guys have any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: seems like permission error. Which user you have used to run the docker?

Comment: Do you mean like on my local machine ? Im using Docker Desktop for macos :)

Comment: i am asking about the docker user

Comment: Well docker user is for sure sudo user on my local machine

Comment: hope this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165119/how-to-resolve-exceptions-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-docker-con

Comment: Well, i have even added root user to dockerfile, but still the same error, my dockerfile is placed in root directory of project, still the same logs